# (Dis)continuity of integral of Riemann integrable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $F\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt$. It's known that if f is Riemann integrable on [a,b], then F is continuous on [a,b].

However, consider

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & x\in[0,0.5]\\
1, & x\in(0.5,1]
\end{cases}$$

which has

$$
F=\begin{cases}
constant, & x\in[0,0.5]\\
x, & x\in(0.5,1]
\end{cases}
$$

As far as I can see, F fails to be continuous for any constant $\neq 0.5$.

Question: what went wrong? Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of $F$ seems to be slightly off. The correct definition would be 
$$F=\begin{cases}
0, & x\in[0,0.5]\\
x\color{red}{-0.5}, & x\in(0.5,1]
\end{cases}$$
This is because you start adding your areas from after $0.5$.

Comment: Why did you choose 0 instead of any constant?

Comment: Because the area under $f(x)$ from $[0,0.5]$ is $0$. As a matter of fact, why didn't you choose $0$?

Comment: Oops, right. Well, I simply integrated mechanically without thinking first. Thank you!